# Is "Zatzal" applied to women? If not, why not?

Tags: women, death, tzaddikim

I have never seen the term Zatzal, which stands for zecher tzadik l'bracha, and is often applied as a sign of respect to deceased righteous men, applied to a deceased righteous woman. I would like to know

1. Are there in fact any recorded examples of this term being applied to a woman?
2. If not, is there a reason?